# Google App Script - How to subtract 7 days from a cell value thats assigned to a variable?

Tags: google-apps-script, scripting, google-sheets-api

I have a script that checks each cell in a specific column, then gets me the value and stores it to a variable. The cells in that column all have different dates in this format. 9/9/2020

I'm trying to figure out how to create another variable that subtracts 7 days from the given date.

Can someone help me with creating a variable that subtracts 7 days from the date grabbed by the "start_date" variable.

Example:

```
var sss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1rIK-TunX1lBlFzndk5L4ExdLQO1GQLwlH-1viZzFZU0');
var ss = sss.getSheetByName('Form Responses 1');

function test() {
  
var lr = ss.getLastRow()

for (var i = 2;i<=lr;i++){   

var start_date = ss.getRange(i,13).getValue();

var minus7days = ??
}}

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!
```

Comment: Also read best practices. You shouldn't be using `getValue()` in a loop.See [tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info) for more details.

Answer (score 2):

### Working with date objects

- When performing calculations with date objects, the best is to convert them to milliseconds.
- This can be done e.g. with [getTime()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime)
- After the calculation you can transform the milliseconds back to a date object with [new Date()](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_dates.asp)

**Sample Code snippet:**

```js
  var ms = start_date.getTime();
  var sevenDays = 7*24*60*60*1000;
  var minus7daysMs = ms - sevenDays;
  var minus7days = new Date(minus7daysMs);
```

Comment: Thanks! one more question if I may. I added a new variable to get me todays date var now = new Date();  and im trying to compare 2 variables with an if statement, and if they are true, then do "stuff" How would I write that? So far I have: if (now == minus7days) do stuff <<< I have the do stuff part under the if statement like it should, but its not working.

Comment: You can not make comparisons with date objects - you need to do it with the values converted to ms - so `if (ms == minus7daysMs) `.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do the same is through [`setDate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setDate), which sets the day of month:

```js
//simulate getValue
const start_date = new Date("2020-9-9");
const minus7date = new Date(start_date);
minus7date.setDate(start_date.getDate()-7);
console.info({start_date,minus7date});
```